# PowerShell cmdlet to apply Password to Never Expire policy in M365 tenancy to all users (including current and new users)

Tags: azure, powershell, office365, microsoft365

I have run the following cmdlet in PowerShell to disable the Password Expiration policy in my M365 tenancy for all users. However, the cmdlet is not applied to new users created. Can someone please explain how I can disable the policy for all current and new users?

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Select-Object UserprincipalName,@{
N="PasswordNeverExpires";E={$_.PasswordPolicies -contains "DisablePasswordExpiration"}
```

}

****EDIT****

I have unchecked the *Set user passwords to expire after a number of days* in the Password expiration policy page. I have run the following cmdlet to check this policy is turned off in PowerShell.

`Get-MsolPasswordPolicy`

[image]

I have run the following cmdlet to set a Password to Never Expire Policy for all users in the organisation. (Upon investiation, this policy only applies to current users, and will not apply to new users).

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Set-AzureADUser -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration
```

Next I have checked the Set Password to Never Expire policy has been implemented successfully:

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Select-Object UserprincipalName,@{
    N="PasswordNeverExpires";E={$_.PasswordPolicies -contains "DisablePasswordExpiration"}
 }
```

[image]

I then created a new user in M365 and ran the same cmdlet again. I can now see that the new user does not have the Password to Never Expire Policy applied.

[image]

Is there a cmdlet to create a Password to Never Expire for all users (current and new users)? I don't want to create separate policies for different users, I want to apply the same policy to all. Please advise.

Comment: ,Could  you please give some insights about New Users, Are you trying to create new user post disabling `PasswordNeverExpires` to existing users or Are you create new user then you are trying to disable the 'PasswordNeverExpires' ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove password expiration for all users, you might consider [changing password expiration policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/set-password-expiration-policy?view=o365-worldwide) for the entire organization.

To do so, uncheck *Set user passwords to expire after a number of days* in [Password expiration policy page](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home?#/Settings/SecurityPrivacy/:/Settings/L1/PasswordPolicy):

[image: Changing password expiration policy]

If you want to set password to never expire for a set of users, but not all, you'd have to schedule a script. The script should find new users and run the cmdlet you used against these new users.

In theory, you could also change password to never expire for all users. That'd require no changes to your script but might affect the performance. It's not recommended, but it might be suitable for smaller organizations.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I've just updated my question with the full process I followed. Can you please read it and advise?

Comment: @Holly S I don't have any way to test it, but I guess you don't need to worry about `PasswordNeverExpires` on user accounts if your org policy is set to 'password never expires'. The only case it might matter could be when password change is forced by risky sign-in/risky user detection - but that's only a guess as I don't know what would happen in such situation

Answer (score 0):

We have tested this in our local environment creating a new user & Using the above shared cmdlets, we are able to disable the Password Expiration policy for  all the existing users & for the new users as well.

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Select-Object UserprincipalName,@{
N="PasswordNeverExpires";E={$_.PasswordPolicies -contains "DisablePasswordExpiration"}}

Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Set-AzureADUser -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration
```

**Here are  the sample output for reference:**

- Below screenshot, is showing the default `PasswordNeverExpires` for all the users.

[image]

- We have created a new user, post running the above cmdlets we are able to change the `PasswordNeverExpires` value to True for all the users as shown in the below

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `MSonline` PowerShell module to enable  `PasswordNeverExpires` value to True.

Here is the PowerShell cmdlets to change the value of `PasswordNeverExpires` value to True for all the users.

```
Connect-MsolService
$userlist = Get-MsolUser -All | select -Property UserPrincipalName,PasswordNeverExpires
foreach( $item in $userlist){
  Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $item.UserPrincipalName -PasswordNeverExpires $true
}
Get-MsolUser -All| select -Property UserPrincipalName,PasswordNeverExpires
```

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

If you still faces the issue would suggest you to open a support ticket using this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) where in  technical support team would help you in troubleshooting the issue from platform end or open a discussion over [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html).

Comment: Thank you VenkateshDodda-MT, I understand this process and have tested it myself successfully. However, my question is how can I create a custom policy that automatically applies to every new user? To be more specific, I want the PasswordNeverExpires policy to automatically apply each time a new user is created, instead of manually running the cmdlet. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below will set the default password policy to never expire for all current and future users.

```
$AllDomains = Get-MsolDomain

ForEach ($domain in $AllDomains){
Set-MsolPasswordPolicy -ValidityPeriod "2147483647" -NotificationDays 0 -DomainName $domain.name
}
```